# Vue lite project not accessible by host in Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

I am trying to use Gitlab for CI/CD. i am using FastAPI as backend. the API is working fine in Docker. But I started a new Docker. it has a problem. It is not accessible by the host. So it causes me to get a 404 error in the browser

I would like to be able to have Vue projects deployed directly into Docker. And access it via the IP address of the host.

### Gitlab CI-File

```
Vue_container_deploy1:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - x=$(docker ps -f "publish=49300" | awk '{print $1}'| sed -n '2p')
      - docker stop $x && docker rm $x
      - docker run -d -p 49300:5173  --network bridge   --name myvue-w1-$CI_PIPELINE_ID   vue:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
      - docker ps
```

### Vue DockerFile

```
FROM node:16.18.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/
# replace this with your application's default port
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
CMD ["npm", "run" ,"serve","-s","dist","--","--host","0.0.0.0"]
```

I wrote a JS. so that Vue3 has different API interface addresses in different development states

### API.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apis = {
  production: 'http://192.168.0.150:49200/blog', // Online (generating environment)
  development: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/', // local (development environment)
  test: 'http://192.168.0.150:49200/blog' // (test environment)
};

const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? apis.production : apis.development;

const ajax = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL
});

export default ajax;
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "serve": "vite",
    "test": "vue-cli-service build --mode test && npm run  serve -s dist",
    "publish": "vue-cli-service build && vue-cli-service build --mode test"
  },
```

### Startup Status Alert

```
  VITE v4.4.4  ready in 337 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://172.17.0.4:5173/
(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
```

I'm trying to understand why Vue's Docker containers can't be accessed by the host machine

I tried to set an IP address when creating the docker. It's the same as the startup prompt. But it's still not accessible

Comment: What URL are you trying to call?  From where?  What result do you get?  Your setup doesn't actually invoke `npm build` at all (all but the last `CMD` are discarded); do you need to `RUN` it?

Comment: I will CMD ["npm", "run", "build"] modify to RUN npm run build.  
It's working normally . Thank you for your help. Have a nice day.